# Pass command output as argument in grep

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

I want to compare two text files for changes line by line. If the files are store locally I know I can do it with

```
grep -Fxvf file1 file2
```

I have a problem because file 2 is in Hadoop File System. I can read this file with the command

```
hadoop fs -cat /filepath/file2
```

So naturally I want to feed this result to grep. I tried something like

```
 grep -Fxvf file1 ${hadoop fs -cat /filepath/file2}
```

but I get

> -bash: ${hadoop fs -cat /filepath/file2}: bad substitution

I tried to use xargs also but with no luck. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @dsstorefile1 I solved it with

```
grep -Fxvf <(hadoop fs -cat /fielpath/file2 ) file1
```